# Create a line break in a CSS flex container with overflow-x set to auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to create different renderings depending on the screen size for a layout part of my website which shows videos.

What I'd like to achieve is to have this layout part shown:

- on big screens as a grid of 6 columns wide, with a featured video shown over 4 columns and 3 rows and regular videos shown in the remaining cells: this works fine
- on small screens as a scrollable element in which the regular videos are shown next to each other, showing at least one or two thumbnails completely and one partly, in order to allow the user to understand that he can scroll right to access other videos, but here also with one featured video being shown differently, screen-wide: this is where I'm having trouble

I manage to correctly show the scrollable element using a container which uses a flex display and with overflow-x set to auto. However, I want a "line break" after my featured video so that the featured video is shown on top screen-wide on a specific row and all regular videos shown together on one row which is scrollable to the right. Since I don't want to modify my HTML code, in order not to alter the way the layout is shown on big screens, I cannot add a "row" div around the featured video and around the regular videos which could allow me to break them up in two.

I've tried a lot, but I don't manage to create the line break/row break, since the only usual solutions I find is to insert a 100% wide element, but since I'm voluntarily with an overflow-x setup that of course doesn't have any particular effect.

Here's my current code:

```
    <div class="videoplayer-container">
        <div class="video featured-video">
            <!-- Featured Entry - YouTube Video Player -->
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="YOUTUBE_EMBED_LINK" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="video">
                <div class="video-overlay">
                    <div class="video-title">Video-title</div>
        </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail for Video 0 -->
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title" title="Video-title" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V0">
        </div>
        <div class="video">
                <div class="video-overlay">
                    <div class="video-title">Video-title1</div>
        </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail for Video 1 -->
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title1" title="Video-title1" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V1">
        </div>
        <div class="video">
                <div class="video-overlay">
                    <div class="video-title">Video-title2</div>
        </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail for Video 2 -->
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title2" title="Video-title2" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V2">
        </div>
        <div class="video">
                <div class="video-overlay">
                    <div class="video-title">Video-title3</div>
        </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail for Video 3 -->
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title3" title="Video-title3" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V3">
        </div>
        <div class="video">
                <div class="video-overlay">
                    <div class="video-title">Video-title4</div>
        </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail for Video 4 -->
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title4" title="Video-title4" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V4">
        </div>
        <div class="video">
                <div class="video-overlay">
                    <div class="video-title">Video-title5</div>
        </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail for Video 5 -->
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title5" title="Video-title5" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V5">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
/* Media Query for wide screens */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
.videoplayer-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #fdc300;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.featured-video {
    grid-column: span 4;
    grid-row: span 3;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.video:hover {
transform: scale(1.05);
}
}

/* Media Query for small screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .videoplayer-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    gap: 10px;
  }

  .video {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #fdc300;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 200px; /* Fixed width for regular videos */
    height: 200px;
  }

  .featured-video {
    flex: 0 0 100%; /* Full width for featured video */
    border: 1px solid #fdc300;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 100%; /* Full width for featured video */
  }
```

You can see how this renders at https://www.velowire.com/videos_tn.responsive.php?l=en. On a mobile device, the element is indeed scrollable to the right, but what I'm trying to do is to have the playable video (the "featured-video") to be on one line, and all the following regular videos on a single second line which is scrollable horizontally.

Said otherwise, what I would like to be able to tell in the code is that after the featured-video (or before the first regular video, both can be coded in of course, I can add a class "first-regular-video" to the first regular video if necessary) I would like to wrap to the next line in the videoplayer-container.

Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For smaller screens keep using grid and increase col span of `feature-video` to full and make video content sticky:

```css
.videoplayer-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.video {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #fdc300;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: lime;
}

.featured-video {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1 15%, #f69d3c 20%);
}

.video:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}


/* Media Query for wide screens */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .featured-video {
    grid-column: span 4;
    grid-row: span 3;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }
}


/* Media Query for small screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .videoplayer-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 200px);
  }

  .video {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .featured-video {
    width: 1300px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-column: span 6;
    grid-row: span 3;
  }

  .featured-video>.iframe {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1 15%, #f69d3c 20%);
    position: sticky;
    height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
    width: calc(100vw - 1rem);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="videoplayer-container">
  <div class="video featured-video">
    <!-- Featured Entry - YouTube Video Player -->
    <div class="iframe" style="display: flex;"><span style="margin: auto;">Featured video</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 0 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title" title="Video-title" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V0">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title1</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 1 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title1" title="Video-title1" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V1">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title2</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 2 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title2" title="Video-title2" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V2">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 3 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title3" title="Video-title3" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V3">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title4</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 4 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title4" title="Video-title4" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V4">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title5</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 5 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title5" title="Video-title5" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V5">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title6</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 5 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title5" title="Video-title5" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V5">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title7</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 5 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title5" title="Video-title5" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V5">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-overlay">
      <div class="video-title">Video-title8</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail for Video 5 -->
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Video-title5" title="Video-title5" data-video-id="YOUTUBE_V5">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** A little bit polishing is needed in above code.

Comment: Hello!

First of all thanks for your reply!

Looking at what you described this sounded very promising to me. However, when implementing it, I realised that this doesn't render as expected.

What I'm looking for actually is something which renders like what's shown in this image https://temp.thover.com/videoplayer_rendering.png (which is actually a mock-up), with the second line scrolling "infinitely" (the number of videos can vary).

Not sure I described this correctly in my initial message, so the image might be better to understand what I'm looking for.